# class creation without xib file

Tags: ios, xib

Should I create .h .m and **xib** files together ? Is it recommended ?

I added a *TextAudioViewController.xib* later and associated it to *TextAudioViewController* class.
I added each outlets.

I have no error in ViewDidLoad. But the view is still empty after tapping into TabBar.

I wonder if it is because I didn't create all files together. A kind of missing link between xib and class files ?

With another class, I created .h .m and xib together and the view was successfully loaded after tapping into TabBar...

EDITED

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (self.tabBarController == nil)
    {
        NSArray* languages = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
        NSString* currentLang = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = @"";

        if ([currentLang isEqual: @"en"] || [currentLang isEqual: @"fr"] || [currentLang isEqual: @"es"])
        {
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:currentLang ofType:@"lproj"];
        }else{
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
        }
        selectedBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
        [self startApplication];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did your initialize your controller with `initWithNibName:` and pass nib name as a parameter?

Comment: I did like it : TextAudioViewController *textAudioController = [[TextAudioViewController alloc] init]; and add it to a pageViewController

Comment: in TextAudioViewController I use initWithNibName but parameter is empty

Comment: TextAudioViewController *textAudioController = [[TextAudioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TextAudioViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: I tried and view is still empty... But I'll edit my post to show you what I did in appdelegate

Comment: I realized I made bundle mistakes in my code need to check everything. It will take time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary that you should create all the files together. After creating the xib file follow these steps.

1.Select the filesowner and change the class name in to TextAudioViewController, you can find the class name under filesinspector.

2.Connect your view outlet to the filesowner view.
Now it shoiuld be working fine.

It is not necessary that you should use initWithNibName:. You can use this only if your class name and xib name are different.